# VPC Network - IP not in use, but actually ping

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I've got one dilemma with external IP

On the External IP addresses, I've got on IP that is not assigned to any of my instances, service, or whatever, but actually, this IP is pingable and got a lot of opened ports including smtp, vnc, rdp, HTTP, and so on.

How the hell I can check where this IP is used and for what purpose?

Comment: maybe this question is more related to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: Show a screenshot of the IP address in the Google Cloud Console. "VPC Networks -> "External IP addresses". That will show you what the address is assigned to. If the address does not show up there, then double check if the IP address is actually for one of the Google Services such as App Engine or Cloud Run. The address will resolve to a Google domain which is the GFE (Google Front End).

Comment: That's the thing - this IP is not assigned anywhere (at least on that view in VPC Networks -> External IP addresses